# CakePHP: How can i get all function names from a Model.php file ? Need a php script

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How can i get all the function names from a cakephp Model.php or from other files of cakephp ?

I don't want to browse api website.

I need to display function name like this..

```
public function query($sql)
public function validates($options = array())
```

I tried this

```
<?php

require_once('Model.php');
$methods = get_class_methods('Model');
print_r($methods);

?>
```

But got error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App' not found in /var/www/cakemyblog/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php on line 25
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/cakemyblog/lib/Cake/Model/countfunction.php:0
PHP   2. require_once() /var/www/cakemyblog/lib/Cake/Model/countfunction.php:3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate the model and pass the object itself:

```
require_once('Model.php');
$Model = new Model();
$methods = get_class_methods($Model);
print_r($methods);
```

But it won't give you the parameters.

**EDIT:**

Looks like you're running this from outside of Cake. You'll need to include all the classes that the *Model* class has dependencies on:

```
require_once 'lib/Cake/Core/App.php';
require_once 'lib/Cake/Core/Object.php';
require_once 'lib/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php';
require_once 'lib/Cake/Model/BehaviorCollection.php';
require_once 'lib/Cake/Utility/Inflector.php';
require_once 'lib/Cake/Utility/ClassRegistry.php';
require_once 'lib/Cake/Model/Model.php';
$methods = get_class_methods('Model');
print_r($methods);
```

Which gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => __call
    [2] => __isset
    [3] => __get
    [4] => bindModel
    [5] => unbindModel
    [6] => setSource
    [7] => set
    [8] => deconstruct
    [9] => schema
    [10] => getColumnTypes
    [11] => getColumnType
    ...
```

Comment: With this you would get error, PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App' not found in /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php on line 25
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/countfunction.php:0
PHP   2. require_once() /var/www/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/countfunction.php:3

Comment: So you are running this from outside of Cake?

Comment: @guru updated my answer to reflect your situation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [get_class_methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) on the file.

Comment: But if i use get_class_methods, i get some errors when it tries to load files from files. See updated original post/question.